# no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

Tags: kubernetes

While deploying mojaloop, Kubernetes responds with the following errors:

> Error: validation failed: [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind
> "Deployment" in version "apps/v1beta2", unable to recognize "": no
> matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1", unable
> to recognize "": no matches for kind "StatefulSet" in version
> "apps/v1beta2", unable to recognize "": no matches for kind
> "StatefulSet" in version "apps/v1beta1"]

My Kubernetes version is 1.16.
How can I fix the problem with the API version?
From investigating, I have found that Kubernetes doesn't support apps/v1beta2, apps/v1beta1.
How can I make Kubernetes use a not deprecated version or some other supported version?

I am new to Kubernetes and anyone who can support me I am happy

Comment: Rewrite your manifest files to use currently supported apis https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/

Comment: how can i reproduce the issue can u share me some step

Comment: https://twitter.com/IanColdwater/status/1213607102595424258

Answer (score 236, accepted):

In Kubernetes 1.16 some `api`s have been changed.

You can check which apis support current Kubernetes object using

```
$ kubectl api-resources | grep deployment
deployments                       deploy       apps                           true         Deployment
```

This means that only apiVersion with `apps` is correct for Deployments (`extensions` is not supporting `Deployment`). The same situation with StatefulSet.

You need to change Deployment and StatefulSet apiVersion to `apiVersion: apps/v1`.

If this does not help, please add your YAML to the question.

**EDIT**
As issue is caused by HELM templates included old apiVersions in Deployments which are not supported in version 1.16, there are 2 possible solutions:

**1.** `git clone` whole repo and replace apiVersion to `apps/v1` in all templates/deployment.yaml using script 
**2.** Use older version of Kubernetes (1.15) when validator accept `extensions` as `apiVersion` for `Deployment` and `StatefulSet`.

Comment: can i downgrade the kubernettes since all the deployment yaml file for mojaloop are compatable with kuberntes version 1.15 so how can i downgrade or by making to downgrade can i get a soln then

Comment: I've check this mojaloop/mojaloop helm chart. Unfortunately, all templates with deployments have apiVersions: `extensions/v1beta1`.
As one of the possible workaround is to `git clone` whole repo and replace apiVersion to `apps/v1` in all templates/deployment.yaml usinc script 
`find . -name 'deployment.yaml' | xargs -n 1 perl -pi -e 's/(apps\/v1beta2)|(extensions\/v1beta1)/apps\/v1/g'.`
Second workaround might be just use older version of Kubernetes (1.15) when validator accept extensions as apiVersion for Deployent and StatefulSet.

Comment: @dan are you using `Minikube` or `Kubeadm`?

Comment: kubeadm i didn't use minikube

Comment: can u share me some steps to the installation of kubeadmn specfic to version 1.15 i can not find specfic resource considering installation of kubeadmn 1.15

Comment: I've seen that you already created question about installation of kubeadm 1.15 and received a good answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58500250/11148139

Answer (score 24):

to convert an older Deployment to apps/v1, you can run:

```
kubectl convert -f ./my-deployment.yaml --output-version apps/v1
```

Comment: Solved it for me - thanks! Just a heads up for the future versions courtesy of the terminal:  
`kubectl convert is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version.
"In order to convert, kubectl apply the object to the cluster, then kubectl get at the desired version"`

Comment: I'm getting `Error: unknown command "convert" for "kubectl"`. I have **kubectl** version `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.4",...`

Comment: @Slaus `kubectl convert` no longer exists as of kubectl 1.22. You can install the separate `kubectl-convert` utility. Info about this can be found under the OS-specific install instructions: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/. For example, here is the MacOS guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/#install-kubectl-convert-plugin

Answer (score 12):

You can change manually as an alternative. Fetch the helm chart:

```
helm fetch --untar stable/metabase
```

Access the chart folder:

```
cd ./metabase
```

Change API version:

```
sed -i 's|extensions/v1beta1|apps/v1|g' ./templates/deployment.yaml
```

Add `spec.selector.matchLabels`:

```
spec:
[...]
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: {{ template "metabase.name" . }}
[...]
```

Finally install your altered chart:

```
helm install ./ \
  -n metabase \
  --namespace metabase \
  --set ingress.enabled=true \
  --set ingress.hosts={metabase.$(minikube ip).nip.io}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 10):

I prefer `kubectl explain`.

```
# kubectl explain deploy
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  apps/v1

DESCRIPTION:
     Deployment enables declarative updates for Pods and ReplicaSets.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources

   kind <string>
     Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object
     represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits
     requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds

   metadata     <Object>
     Standard object metadata.

   spec <Object>
     Specification of the desired behavior of the Deployment.

   status       <Object>
     Most recently observed status of the Deployment.
```

With `kubectl explain` you can also see specific parameters of an object:

```
# kubectl explain Service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy
KIND:     Service
VERSION:  v1

FIELD:    externalTrafficPolicy <string>

DESCRIPTION:
     externalTrafficPolicy denotes if this Service desires to route external
     traffic to node-local or cluster-wide endpoints. "Local" preserves the
     client source IP and avoids a second hop for LoadBalancer and Nodeport type
     services, but risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading. "Cluster"
     obscures the client source IP and may cause a second hop to another node,
     but should have good overall load-spreading.
```

Answer (score 8):

To put it simply, you don't force the current installation to use an outdated version of the API; you fix the version in your config files.
If you want to check which version your current kube supports, run :

```sh
root@ubn64:~# kubectl api-versions | grep -i apps

apps/v1
```

Answer (score 7):

I was getting below error -
error: unable to recognize "deployment.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "extensions/v1beta1"

solution that worked for me -

**modified the line from apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 to apiVersion: apps/v1 in deployment.yaml**

Reason -
we had upgraded the K8 cluster hence this error occured.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue on a cluster that was upgraded to a version that does not support certain api versions (v1.17 and apps/v1beta2).

```
$ helm get manifest some-deployment
...
# Source: some-deployment/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: some-deployment
  labels:
...
```

Looking at the helm docs, it seems that the manifest is stored in the cluster for helm to reference, and it may include invalid api versions, leading to errors.

The 2 [proposed methods](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/kubernetes_apis/#updating-api-versions-of-a-release-manifest) are to either manually edit the manifest (a rather tedious multi-stage process), or use a helm plugin called [`mapkubeapis`](https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis) that does it automatically.

```
$ helm plugin install https://github.com/helm/helm-mapkubeapis
```

It can be run with the `--dry-run` flag to simulate the effects:

```
$ helm mapkubeapis --dry-run some-deployment
2021/02/15 09:33:29 NOTE: This is in dry-run mode, the following actions will not be executed.
2021/02/15 09:33:29 Run without --dry-run to take the actions described below:
2021/02/15 09:33:29
2021/02/15 09:33:29 Release 'some-deployment' will be checked for deprecated or removed Kubernetes APIs and will be updated if necessary to supported API versions.
2021/02/15 09:33:29 Get release 'some-deployment' latest version.
2021/02/15 09:33:30 Check release 'some-deployment' for deprecated or removed APIs...
2021/02/15 09:33:30 Found deprecated or removed Kubernetes API:
"apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment"
Supported API equivalent:
"apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment"
2021/02/15 09:33:30 Finished checking release 'some-deployment' for deprecated or removed APIs.
2021/02/15 09:33:30 Deprecated or removed APIs exist, updating release: some-deployment.
2021/02/15 09:33:30 Map of release 'some-deployment' deprecated or removed APIs to supported versions, completed successfully.
```

and then run without the flag to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This was annoying me because I am testing lots of helm packages so I wrote a quick script - which could be modified to sort your workflow perhaps
see below

New workflow
First fetch the chart as a tgz to your working directory

```
helm fetch repo/chart
```

then in your working directly run bash script below - which I named helmk

```
helmk myreleasename mynamespace chart.tgz [any parameters for kubectl create]
```

Contents of helmk - need to edit your kubeconfig clustername to work

```
#!/bin/bash
echo usage $0 releasename namespace chart.tgz [createparameter1] [createparameter2] ... [createparameter n]
echo This will use your namespace then shift back to default so be careful!!
kubectl create namespace $2   #this will create harmless error if namespace exists have to ignore
kubectl config set-context MYCLUSTERNAME --namespace $2
helm template -n $1 --namespace $2 $3 | kubectl convert -f /dev/stdin | kubectl create --save-config=true ${@:4}  -f /dev/stdin
#note the --namespace parameter in helm template above seems to be ignored so we have to manually switch context
kubectl config set-context MYCLUSTERNAME --namespace default
```

It's a slightly dangerous hack since I manually switch to your new desired namespace context then back again so only to be used for single user devs really or comment that out.

You will get a warning about using the kubectl convert facility like this

If you need to edit the YAML to customise - just replace one of the /dev/stdin to intermediate files but It's probably better to get it up using "create" with a save-config as I have and then simply "apply" your changes which means that they will be recorded in kubernetes too.
Good luck