# Can u share me an installation document specifically version 1.15 for kubeadmn

Tags: kubernetes

can anyone share me clear step installation specific to 1.15 for kubernettes admn?
 I am new for Kubernetes and i didn't able to find for installation steps version specific for kubeadm if anyone can you share some link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the link to install k8s cluster using kubeadm

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

you just need to include the kubernetes version parameter to install specific version as shown below.

```
kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=v1.15.0
```

Comment: while installing according to the document u shared me it installs version 1.16 that I didn't wont to be installed please can share how can I install kubeadmn specifically version 1.15

Comment: can I install kubeadm 1.15 by itself I have installed kubectl 1.15 but I need to install kubeadm with version 1.15 or do I miss some things?

Comment: you need to install kubectl, kubeadm and kubelet with version 1.15.0 then run kubeadm init command

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install Kubernetes cluster in version other then current is to install `kubeadm`, `kubectl` and `kubelet` in the version you want. This is because `kubeadm` will download the newest version of `kubelet` and `kubectl` as additional packages.

Which will lead to an error while doing `kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=v1.15.0`

> [ERROR KubeletVersion]: the kubelet version is higher than the control plane version. This is not a supported version skew and may lead to a malfunctional cluster. Kubelet version: "1.16.2" Control plane version: "1.15.0"`

Correct way of installing not latest version of Kubernetes cluster is to install all packages with the same version which can be done for example using:

`apt-get install kubeadm=1.15.0-00 kubelet=1.15.0-00 kubectl=1.15.0-00`