# Unable to helm install due to deployment manifest issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

While trying to perform `helm install`

> Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest:
>   [unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Service" in version
>   "extensions/v1beta1", error validating "": error validating data:
>   ValidationError(Deployment.spec): missing required field "selector" in
>   io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DeploymentSpec]

My `service.yaml` looks like below

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helm-xxx-helper-api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 31235
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
     app: helm-xxx-helper
```

My `deployment.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helm-xxx-helper
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
    name: helm-xxx-helper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helm-xxx-helper
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helm-xxx-helper
        image: xxxxxxxxx:5001/devops/xxx-helper:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: XXX_STAGE
            value: "DEV"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you running? `extensions/v1beta1` was removed in I believe 1.16.

Comment: @HariEnnekat change the `apiVersion: v1` and correct the format in the Deployment.yaml `.spec.selector.matchLabels`. Then everything should be fine.

Comment: @doelleri Yes, I am using version 1.16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you received this error it means that you are using version Kubernetes 1.16 or newer.

**Issue 1** - With `Service`

In this version many `apiVersion` has been changed (Deployments, StatefulSet, Service). More details can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/07/18/api-deprecations-in-1-16/).

In Kubernetes 1.16 you need to use `apiVersion: v1` for `service`. Otherwise you will receive errors like

```
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Service" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Service" in version "extensions/v1"
error: unable to recognize "STDIN": no matches for kind "Service" in version "apps/v1"
```

**Issue 2** - With `Deployment`.

- `spec.selector.matchLabels` does not contain value like `name`. You need to use value from `labels`. So in this case instead of `name: helm-xxx-helper` you need to use `app: helm-xxx-helper` otherwise you will receive error like:

```
The Deployment "helm-xxx-helper" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"app":"helm-xxx-helper"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`
```

- wrong YAML format. In your code you have

```
...
selector:
  matchLabels:
  name: helm-xxx-helper
...
```

Value for `matchLabels` should be under 3rd letter (t). Also as I mentioned in previous point you need to change `name` to `app`

Proper format with correct valye of `matchLables`:

```
...
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: helm-xxx-helper
...
```

You can read about `Labels` and `Selectors` [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

As you mentioned it is `HELM`, you will need to change `Kubernetes version` to older than 1.16 or change `apiVersion` in each object YAML in  `template` directory.
There was already a similar case. Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58482194/11148139) for more information.

Below both YAMLs which will create `Service` and `Deployment`. Tested on Kubernetes 1.16.1.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: helm-xxx-helper-api
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - nodePort: 31235
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: helm-xxx-helper
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: helm-xxx-helper
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helm-xxx-helper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: helm-xxx-helper
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: helm-xxx-helper
        image: nginx # As I dont have your image ive put nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
          - name: XXX_STAGE
            value: "DEV"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: This is upto the point. Identified all the issues associated with it. I'm choosing this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this in selector

```
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: helm-xxx-helper
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case CRD was missing. created CRD and issue resolved.