# Pushing to Azure Container Registry gives 404 not found

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-container-registry

I'm trying to push a chart to my ACR by following the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos).

I'm getting a 404 not found error, And I can't seem to find why this is thrown.

Script:

```
export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
echo $(registryPassword) | helm registry login $(registryServerName) -u $(registryLogin) --password-stdin
helm chart save charts/$(projectName) $(registryServerName)/$(imageName):$(imageTag)
helm chart list
helm chart push $(registryServerName)/$(imageName):$(imageTag):v0.3.5
```

Logs:

```
Login succeeded
ref:     <omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1048:v0.3.5
digest:  a0cd7f0f9a47469915a8c8199ecbe00fc4bed094fcf4002d0e602eea2f76473c
size:    1.6 KiB
name:    client-angular
version: v0.3.5
v0.3.5: saved
REF                                                 NAME            VERSION DIGEST  SIZE        CREATED           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1034:v0.3.4 client-angular  v0.3.4  396e4d0 1.6 KiB     17 hours          
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1036:v0.3.4 client-angular  v0.3.4  35afa1f 1.6 KiB     2 hours           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1040:v0.3.4 client-angular  v0.3.4  b3c7d09 1.6 KiB     2 hours           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1042:v0.3.5 client-angular  v0.3.5  d857c2f 1.6 KiB     2 hours           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1044:v0.3.5 client-angular  v0.3.5  b3b0b0a 1.6 KiB     About an hour     
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1046:v0.3.5 client-angular  v0.3.5  cc2be7a 1.6 KiB     18 minutes        
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1048:v0.3.5 client-angular  v0.3.5  a0cd7f0 1.6 KiB     Less than a second
<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:979:v0.3.4  client-angular  v0.3.4  52ba3b4 1.6 KiB     10 days           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/server:1035:v0.3.4         server          v0.3.4  1190dc2 43.1 KiB    17 hours          
<omitted>.azurecr.io/server:1037:v0.3.4         server          v0.3.4  da1d991 43.1 KiB    2 hours           
<omitted>.azurecr.io/server:1045:v0.3.4         server          v0.3.4  7bb4611 43.1 KiB    About an hour     
<omitted>.azurecr.io/server:1047:v0.3.5         server          v0.3.5  1cf51bf 43.1 KiB    21 minutes        
<omitted>.azurecr.io/server:980:v0.3.4          server          v0.3.4  7915917 43.1 KiB    10 days           
The push refers to repository [<omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1048]
ref:     <omitted>.azurecr.io/client-angular:1048:v0.3.5
digest:  a0cd7f0f9a47469915a8c8199ecbe00fc4bed094fcf4002d0e602eea2f76473c
size:    1.6 KiB
name:    client-angular
version: v0.3.5
Error: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:efeac2a2a1b8b3dc18e4cfc439a765d4c03720aa829756dc94e7b1708d9196bf": unexpected status: 404 Not Found
```

When looking at the documentation this shoul dbe fine, but still it's complaining.
Anybody got an idea?

Comment: share the docker config file

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry, I'm kinda new with this, What file is it you are referring to?

Comment: how are you deploying the app ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Kiwi is deploying a chart, no an app

Comment: Any update on this, i am also getting the same error on helm v3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

As I see, all the steps are right. The problem is in your helm chart. The error shows the manifest no found. You can check if there is something wrong with your chart. For example, some formats wrong. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369174/unable-to-helm-install-due-to-deployment-manifest-issue) is a similar issue that the manifest cannot found.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and this is how I resolved it.

The name of my helm chart was `SampleApp` and I renamed it to `sampleapp`. After that pushing the helm chart to ACR succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

When using helm push to upload a chart an OCI registry, the reference must be prefixed with oci:// and must not contain the basename or tag.

so helm push <file-1.2.3.tgz> oci://myregistry/file

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/