# Getting error while running "Harbor" in Kubernetes Cluster set up locally using Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-registry, kubernetes-pod, harbor

While running Harbor, a caching service for K8s, I'm getting the following error:

> error: unable to recognize "harbor.yaml": no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "v1.10.1"

Is there documentation for a working version of Harbor yet?

Comment: please add the contents of your harbor.yaml you may just need to change the api version of your deployment

Comment: https://superusersudo.blogspot.com/2020/03/yaml-for-running-harbor-in-kubernetes.html

Please refer to the YAML here

Answer (score 1):

There is [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481850/no-matches-for-kind-deployment-in-version-extensions-v1beta1) due to changes in `k8s` API.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58481850/no-matches-for-kind-deployment-in-version-extensions-v1beta1)

> This means that only apiVersion with `apps` is correct for Deployments (`extensions` is not supporting `Deployment`)

And there is fix in the [harbor helm chart](https://github.com/goharbor/harbor-helm/pull/377)
Update your configs and check configs.

There is a workaround to fix it manually: replace `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1`

```
sed -i 's#extensions/v1beta1#apps/v1# *.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

An yaml for deployment should have `apiVersion: apps/v1`

An easy way to install harbor is using helm from [helm hub](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/harbor/harbor)